# my bot cant find a directory even though it does exist discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a very complex bot set up that runs five screens to split up different processes. I am trying to make a dynamic help command that will grab all the commands from all the different directories but telling it to grab this one '../../moderation/commands' returns an error where the directory does not exist. the command that needs to find the directories is two folders deep from the rest of the main folders and each of those has a commands folder in it. 'bot/publicbot/commands' i need to see 'bot/moderation/commands' and 'bot/music/commands' as well. this is my current code

```
const { commands } = message.client;
        const modCommands = fs.readdirSync(`../../Moderation/commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(`.js`));
        for (const file of modCommands) {
            commands = commands + require(`../../Moderation/commands/${file}`);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fs methods find the path relative to the bot directory, not the current file.  Therefore, try `fs.readdirSync(‘./Moderation/commands’)` but leave the `require()` unchanged.